# Google Classroom APIS: Read Announcements, Questions and Assignments within courses

Tags: rest, google-api, google-plus, google-classroom

I am reading [Google Classroom Rest APIs](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/) and not getting clear answers as to how can I get full access to specific course including Announcements, Questions and Assignments.

Use Case:

Lets say we get all the courses using: [List](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses/list) 
and [Students List](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/list)

Now, How can I get all the Students Announcements, Questions and Assignments posted in specific course.

Is there a Google+ apis that we can use injunction with Classroom or just Classroom apis that we can use to access this critical information?

I am trying to merge existing platform with google classroom and its very critical to have access to this information so that all student submissions are in sync.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Classroom API does not have the functionality you are referring to. From the documentation:

> The Classroom API provides a RESTful interface for you to manage
>   courses and rosters in Google Classroom.

All it currently does is allow you to manage a list of courses, their teachers, and their students.

If you want manage additional data such as Assignments, you'll need to build that functionality yourself. The [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk) and [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) may be of assistance in storing and sharing files and documents.

Answer (score 0):

probably you have found by now else FYI.. Google has released a new set of APIs to manage assignments under ManageCourse-work

https://developers.google.com/classroom/